# download file (blob) as .env

Tags: javascript, download, environment-variables

I'm currently working on creating an application that generates .env file for the upcoming projects.
I'm using simple blob method to download the json I create via my application, however I still haven't found the way to download file as .env instead of .txt, .csv and etc.. If anyone knows a method, would be very grateful, thanks.

Code I'm using to download my json

```
  const downloadEnv = async (filename, text) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dictionary)) {
      setEnvContent(envContent + `${key}= ${value}` + "\n") 
    }
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(envContent));
      element.setAttribute('download', 'filename');
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

As you can see for now I download content as txt.

Comment: Have you tried setting the extension to .env in the download attribute?

Comment: I've managed to download file as .env yet now my issue is that it doesn't download as '.env' but '_.env', anything I try leads to this stupid underline appearing instead of empty space.